# SearchView in Toolbar: the second icon doesn't appear properly

Tags: android, android-toolbar, searchview

I don't understand why the second icon (filter) is appeared not properly (no padding on right?). Have you got some ideas guys?

[image]

This is my menu setup xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_input_search"
        android:title="@string/search"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:visible="false"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_tb"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:visible="false"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_filter"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_filter_tb"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:visible="false"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

Comment: SearchView has some bugs, so you may want to make your custom one. In this case a quick workaround to place the filter icon on the other side, but it's probably not what you want.

Comment: Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/27608049/11880323